# Trouble in Nesting a fragment within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

I'm beginner to java and android, and i'm currently working on a project in which i have situation of using fragment within a fragment,and i have written a program (mentioned below) from which i am facing an app crash.

main fragment:

```
public class Register extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {
    FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
    ImageButton newReg;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View register = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register, container, false);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        newReg = (ImageButton) register.findViewById(R.id.newreg);
        newReg.setOnClickListener(this);
        return register;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fragment details = new Details();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(details, "adada");
        transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

nested fragment:

```
public class Details extends Fragment {
    EditText firstN,lastN,Phone,Email;
    Button Confirm;
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View details=inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_details, container, false);
    return details;
}
}
```

Logcat output:

```
    08-22 15:30:32.907: D/OpenGLRenderer(31032): Enabling debug mode 0
08-22 15:30:35.095: D/AndroidRuntime(31032): Shutting down VM
08-22 15:30:35.095: W/dalvikvm(31032): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41674d40)
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032): Process: com.example.apeonomy, PID: 31032
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032): java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1049)
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1044)
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1853)
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032):    at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1714)
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:908)
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-22 15:30:35.099: E/AndroidRuntime(31032):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Provide some information about the crash. Paste the logcat here

Comment: based on `08-22 15:15:48.028: W/System.err(30119): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Button cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageButton` post `R.layout.register` aka `\layout\register.xml`

Comment: i changed it from ImageButton to Button, but still the app crashes..

Comment: Try to clean and run again and check

Comment: The logcat should be changed now, is it changed?

Comment: i have edited the logcat and uploaded, plz check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put a FrameLayout in your register.xml file like this

```
 <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/anyView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/anyOtherView" 
/>
```

FrameLayout work as a container. Then modify your onClick( View v) method like this:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Fragment details = new Details();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity()
                .getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, details);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you ali for your time. I got the solution and was about you post  as an answer to my problem...

Answer (score 0):

Logcat shows the problematic Line:

```
newReg = (ImageButton) register.findViewById(R.id.newreg);
```

You have defined **newreg** as a **Button** in xml file **register**, and you are initializing it as a **ImageButton**.

Answer (score 0):

Check your layout file register.xml. The view with the id `newreg` is a `Button` type but you are casting it to be an `ImageButton` when you try to get it in `onCreateView`.

Comment: It was a button and I changed from imagebutton to button, but still it crashes...

Comment: OK, that's a completely different crash.  You'll have to provide more of the code: the Activity and more from both Fragments.  Otherwise there's not enough of a picture of what is going on.